# Am I not able to throw specific exception

Tags: java

```
@Override
Public class example {
void test {
try {
  someMethod(); //This throws TimeoutException
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
  throw new TimeoutException(ex); //It doesn't throw error if I replace this with throw new RuntimeException(ex)
} }
}
```

The above example gives an error as 'throw new TimeoutException(ex)' as "TimeoutException(java.lang.string) in java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException cannot be applied to (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException)".

But it doesn't throw an error if I replace it with 'throw new RuntimeException(ex)';

Comment: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException has no consturctor that accepts other exceptions

Comment: you want to pack a `TimeoutException` within a `TimeoutException`. What you need to do is `throw ex;` as this is already the exact exception you want to throw

Comment: Indeed, `TimeoutException`  doesn't have such a constructor : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException.html

Comment: @XtremeBaumer or just not catch it in the first place.

Comment: throw ex; errors saying unhandled Exception.

Comment: If you add `throws TimeoutException` to your method declaration, then you don't need to catch it.

Comment: `Throwable` has a method `initCause(Throwable cause)`. See my answer. I'm not sure it's great design, it seems to exist to avoid having twice as many constructors or except the caller to pass `null` most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

`TimeoutException` doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `TimeoutException` as an argument of the form `TimeoutException(TimeoutException cause)` or similar.

You can instead:

```
TimeoutException localtoe=new TimeoutException("test failed");
localtoe.initCause(ex);
throw localtoe;
```

Or equally:

```
throw new TimeoutException("test failed").initCause(ex);
```

`initCause()` may only be called once and only if cause wasn't set by a constructor. It's a funny little method that acts like a constructor after-thought(*).

There's nothing necessarily wrong with wrapping an exception as the cause of an exception.
Suppose `testFunction()` connects and then performs some operation.
You might want to throw an exception with message "connection failed in testFunction" and another "operation failed in testFunction" depending on what sub-step failed.

But if you don't need to provide so much detail you can just `throw ex` or let the method unwind without itself catching anything.

Here's a little example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

class Example{

private static void connect() throws TimeoutException {
        //Dummy connection that just fails...   
        throw new TimeoutException("connection failed");
    }

    private static void process() throws TimeoutException {
        try {
            connect();
        }catch(TimeoutException toe){
           TimeoutException toeout=new TimeoutException("process failed because connection failed.");
           toeout.initCause(toe);
           throw toeout;
        }
        //Code for when connection succeeds...
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try{
            process();  
        }catch(TimeoutException toe){
            System.out.println(toe);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: process failed because connection failed.
```

(*) `initCause()` looks like an after-thought and is somewhat. It was added to Java 1.4 in 2002. The documentation talks about 'legacy' constructors. Rather than double up the number of constuctors (to add one with a `Throwable cause` argument) it appears it was decided to allow this as bolt-on initialization.
It's debatable whether that was the best solution.

Comment: You may want to consider not wrapping that `TimeoutException` in yet another `TimeoutException` as that doesn't make a lot of sense. That would also simplify `process()` as you can do away with the try-catch entirely.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel. I suggest that and agree it's probably overkill to wrap the exception. But I hate answers that just tell people not to do something rather than how to do it. As I said in the answer, you might have a method that has multiple steps each of which might time-out and what to indicate which failed. Timeout on connect may have a different environment cause to some operation. 
Still think its overkill, but none of the other answers mentioned `initCause()` which is how to do it if you really feel the need.

Answer (score 0):

You have roughly three options here:

1. Rethrow the same exception: `throw ex;'
2. Throw a new `TimeoutException` and lose the stack trace: `throw new TimeoutException(ex.getMessage());`
3. Throw an exception of another type, such as `RuntimeException`.

Each of these options have advantages and drawbacks, you decide.

UPDATE (thanks to @Mark Rottenveel)

Point 2 could be rewritten: `throw new TimeoutException(ex.getMessage()).initCause(ex);` to keep the link to the original exception.

Comment: From AndyTurner: `or just not catch it in the first place` (add `throws` to method signature)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer fair enough

Comment: First two option gives an error saying, unhandled Exception.

Comment: @KishoreKumar yes, that is because you have not declares `TimeoutException` as thrown in your method.

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of the `initCause(Throwable)` method? That means with option 2 you can also **not** lose the stack trace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Things I observed in your question

1. you are trying to call a method directly from class in a try cache block. which is wrong you have to create method and call it from that
2. you want to throw an exception. SO you have to throw it method level from where you are calling it

please find the demo solution below :

```
public class example {

public void testFunction() throws TimeoutException {
    try {
        someFunction();
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        throw ex; 
    }
}

public void someFunction() throws TimeoutException {

}
}
```

Comment: There's no need to catch the exception and re-throw it. You can get rid of the `try/catch` entirely.

Comment: A practice like that would mean you'd log the exception multiple times. You usually only log where you handle the exception, not in the steps in between.

Answer (score 0):

Java has 2 categories of exceptions: checked and unchecked. Checked exception (usually subclasses of `Exception`) must be declared in function signatures, while unchecked ones (usually subclasses of `RuntimeException`) must not.

`TimeoutException` is a checked exception. When it could be thrown from a method that does not declare it, you have 2 options:

- declare it in the signature:

  ```
  public void func1() throws TimeoutException {
      somefunction();
  }
  ```

  clean and simple but it can be problemetic is func1 is an override of a function not declared to throw this exception, of it it is called from another function (suppose from a framework) that does not declare it either
- *hide* it in an unchecked exception

  ```
  public void func1() {
      try {
          somefunction();
      } catch (TimeoutException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
  }
  ```

  you lose the declarative part (checked exceptions exist for that reason), but at least it allows you to call it from function not declaring it.